# Is this a valid proof method (and how to complete it) of the exchange of order of indexed summations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, summation

I want to prove that
$$
\sum_{1 \leqq i \leqq a} \sum_{1 \leqq j \leqq b} f(i, j) = \sum_{1 \leqq j \leqq b}\sum_{1 \leqq i \leqq a} f(i, j)
$$

Which is a very simple statement, but also a bit vexing to try to prove.

I know that this can be done using induction (strong induction on the size of $a + b$, i.e. showing that assuming it is true for $a + b < n$ then it also holds for $a + b  = n$), but I want to find an elegant, simple proof. One thing I thought would be nice is to build a set, which contains all the members of the LHS, i.e.

$$
S = \{f(i, j) : 1 \leqq i \leqq a \land 1 \leqq j \leqq b\}
$$

And then show that this contains all the members of the first sum, but here I got stuck. If the sum was a set (well, first I wouldn't have the problem of needing to turn it into a set, but ignoring that) then I could show that there is a bijection between the sum and the set (and that this function is isomorphic, in that it preserves addition), but the sum is not a set.

If that were possible, then I would use the commutativity of logical and, i.e. that

$$
\{f(i, j) : 1 \leqq i \leqq a \land 1 \leqq j \leqq b\} = \{f(i, j) : 1 \leqq j \leqq b \land 1 \leqq i \leqq a\}
$$

And then I would apply the same process (the one I'm unsure on how to define) to show that therefore $S$ is also isomorphic to the RHS.

I tried to do some thinking about how to define this process, and I wasn't really sure how to write this mathematically. I'm not sure if it follows from the definition of sigma notation directly that this $S$ exists (with the desired properties).

Another approach along the same lines I tried was to show that the sums are equivalent by something a bit like the method of double counting - showing that a term is in the LHS iff it is the RHS, by considering an arbitrary $(i, j)$ in the LHS and then showing that the term is also in the RHS (and vice versa), but I don't know if this counts as a proof.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are a and b integers? As far as I know when the two summations are finite there's no problem to change their order. This follows from Fubini's theorem (which is way more general). Also... actually in case of finite sums the statement is pretty obvious, because you're basically summing up a table, first by rows, then by columns. Just write down all $f(i,j)$ in a table.

Comment: There is a nice visual "proof" by ordering the values $f(i,j)$ in an $a\times b$ rectangle and noticing that we can traverse them row by row or column by column. For a rigorous proof though, I don't think there's an easier way than induction.

Comment: @peter.petrov isn't Fubini's theorem about multiple integrals, so it's probably necessary (for the sake of non-circularity) to show that this is true (as the proof of Fubini's theorem probably relies on this somewhere, even if implicitly)?

Comment: There's another theorem about sums which is also called Fubini's theorem. I was referring to that one. You can check the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Apologies and thank you!